# Two different buffers, same python shell

Tags: python, emacs, python-mode

I just started using emacs, and installed python-mode.el, along with a few extra add-ins (following Jess Hamrick's setup in [Emacs as a python IDE](http://www.jesshamrick.com/2012/09/18/emacs-as-a-python-ide/)).

I find myself with one tricky issue. I want to edit different buffers, but I want to be able to send code from both of them to my python shell. Unfortunately, when I try to send code from a file buffer using `C-c |`, a new python buffer is opened for it, and I can't figure out how to instruct emacs to send it to the original python shell buffer.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A report at

https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode

would be useful, as it turns out there is not test for this.
However, when checking it works nice here.

A reason for using a different output-buffer might be a different python-version in a shebang.  Each python version connects to its own process and thus gets its own output-buffer. And running it dedicated would open a new process/buffer every time.

What's the python-mode.el version?

Setting `py-split-windows-on-execute-p` to `nil` might help.